# How to import css/js in spring MVC application jsp page

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I am new to spring mvc , I am creating a user registration page , there I need to put external css and import external js .

I put the script tag with src and link tag with href. But i think in Spring MVC application they will not work straight forward.
For this I added resourceservlet mapping but still it is not working

I am not able to find any way how I csn include these assets in my jsp file.

Please help me to get this one.

Regards,
Pranav

Comment: I am using spring 3.0 . I am not able to find any such type of mapping.

Comment: I am getting the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the CSS, JS, image files, etc., into a directory (which may contain subdirectories) in your web site, and than map the requests to that directory:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

In this example the files are in the `public-resources` directory, and you refer to them using `/resources` in the link in your JSP.

For more information see [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)